# How can I stream locally generated information to API function using Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, server

I would like to host a process on my computer (locally) that continuously generates a new sequence of numbers and streams it to an API so that users can go to a web application and see the most recent numbers generated on my computer. I'm using the Flask module in python 3 and this is what I have so far. Ideally, new numbers would be generated every second after the execution of the script and tapping into the API would show the most recent.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
import time
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    return flask.request.args.get('numbers')

while True:
    numbers = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
    app.run()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this and then pipe into 127.0.0.1:5000, I get the following error:

```
[2020-07-18 20:40:36,277] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\Pyt3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\Pyt3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\Pyt3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\Pyt3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2020 20:40:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't the solution to your question, but the reason that you are you are receiving this error is because your function is not returning a valid response. typical responses are either a string or json created using the jsonify function imported from flask.

Comment: You can use a global variable and assign a new random number to it by using a separate thread, your API endpoint will return the value of the global variable.

You can use something like this:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
to generate the number every selected period of time